# Enabling Touch Keyboard Swipe and Predictive Text Features in Unity 3D for Windows 10

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, windows-10, typing

I am currently developing a standalone Unity 3D application for Windows 10 and have encountered a challenge with the [input fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfdPI.png). Specifically, when users interact with these fields using the Windows Touch Keyboard, the functionality seems limited. The issues are as follows:

The Touch Keyboard only permits the entry of one character at a time.
There's an absence of predictive text suggestions.
[Swipe typing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9qZn.png), a common feature in other Windows applications (like text editors and search boxes), is not available.
To provide a clearer picture, I'm referring to the swipe typing method typically seen in mobile OS keyboards. This feature greatly enhances user experience, especially for touchscreen device users.

I'm seeking guidance on how to modify Unity 3D input fields to support these advanced features of the Windows Touch Keyboard. Any insights or suggestions on how to implement swipe typing and predictive text within Unity 3D would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On your Input Field, there should be a bool called `Autocorrected`. If you enable this, it should bring the predictive text but is only used on mobile. The [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField.InputType.AutoCorrect.html) do not mention if it works on Desktop. I would give this a try first.

Comment: I have already tried, it doesn't work for windows 10

Comment: @EgorBaydarov I found a [thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/no-keyboard-on-windows-8.186697/) that is a bit old, but it appears in 2013 there was no public API to access this keyboard. I do not know if this has changed.